# Two different SHA1 fingerprints from Idea and cmd

Tags: java, android, keytool, android-fingerprint-api

Am getting two different SHA1  fingerprints from IDEA by running signing report task and from cmd using the `keytool -list -v -keystore` command. What could be causing this? Is this normal? And if it is, which one do I use to get an API key?

Comment: Which command you run for gettting sha-1 inside cmd?

Comment: @Kabir keytool -list -v -keystore path/file.jks -alias filekey